# Combine cluster and categorical mapping on Cartodb

Tags: carto, cartocss

I came across this [map](https://homeland.house.gov/map/) that shows clusters but when you zoom in, the they split into points reflecting categorical data.

How do I replicate this on cartodb?

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that you would need to use [CARTO.js](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/) and the [CARTO SQL API](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/sql-api/). [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/ernesmb/348b9eed9ee4c7038fd7) you can find an example that aggregates and displays data according to a category.